# Robolectric testing activity creation including intent extras

Tags: android, tdd, android-2.3-gingerbread, robolectric, android-testing

I have an activity that will grab a pojo from the extras, like so :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            MyPojo pojo = extras.getParcelable("pojo");
            // do stuff with my pojo here
            }
        }
        // button that shows a toast message
    }
```

I'm having difficulty being able to test this using Robolectric, I believe I need to use a combination of ShadowIntents and ShadowActivities, but the documentation is a little thin, and any useful tutorials on this particular scenario are rather sparse.

This is what I've come up with so far :

```
@Test
    public void assertClickingTagSightingDisplaysToast()
    {
        myActivity = new MyActivity();
        myActivity.onCreate(null);
        ShadowActivity shadowMyActivity = shadowOf(myActivity);
        shadowMyActivity.setIntent(new Intent().putExtra("pojo", generateAPojo()));


        ShadowButton shadowButton = (ShadowButton) shadowOf(shadowMyActivity.findViewById(R.id.myButton));
        shadowButton.performClick();

        assertThat(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast(), equalTo("Button was clicked!"));
    }
```

I keep getting a null pointer when I execute these tests, at the `getIntent().getExtras()` line of my activity, I'm assuming that my process of mocking the activities with intents is incorrect.

can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hit this very thing myself.  It *seems* that you need to use the shadowActivity to manipulate the Intent, prior to calling your onCreate().

```
Robolectric.shadowOf(activity).setIntent(intent);
```

Seems like manipulating the activity itself should do the trick, but it doesn't.  Somebody *way* smarter than me will have to explain why this is -- or someone only modestly smarter than me to tell you that the above is wrong.

-- Quick note. Since Robolectric appears to be using javassist to manipulate the shadow classed, it's important to do your class binding prior to the first load of a class.  I followed their suggestion to do the binding in the Runner.

Comment: there is still no answer :)