# Robolectric: testing an Activity, expecting extras (version 2.X)

Tags: robolectric

I want to test an activity, to which some information is passed in extras.

```
Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra("someData", "asdfgh");
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(XYZ.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
```

It throws following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:4993)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:92)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:117)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:256)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:114)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:126)
at com.XXX.XXX.XYZTest.shouldDoBlah(XYZTest.java:XX)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
```

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10787928/1000837) in some manner. However, the answer seems to be outdated. It would have worked well in older versions of Robolectric.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529427/1000837) answer seems to work for me. However, can somebody confirm this as the correct way of doing. Because in the previous versions `new Intent().putExtra(String, String)` used to work fine.

This is what I did:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext(), XYZ.class);
intent.putExtra("foo", "bar");
XYZ xyz = Robolectric.buildActivity(XYZ.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
```

You need to pass a context and the class (you want to test) as parameters of the Intent constructor.
Hope it helps.

**For Roboelectric Version 3.1+**

`withIntent(intent)` method is deprecated, as per the document intent should be passed through the constructor instead.

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(XYZ.class, intent).create().get();
```

Comment: Thanks you guy, you help me a lot.

Answer (score 9):

In robolectric 3.x the way to get the application context is a little different:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),
                ViewTransactionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(foo, bar);
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(XYZ.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In 3.0 snapshot of robolectric the api is changed to :

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString(Constants.PASSWORD_RESET_MESSAGE, "");
   intent.putExtras(bundle);
   mTargetActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(Target.class).withIntent(intent).create().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems withIntent method is deprecated. Alternative is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent.putExtra("extra", "test");

Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(YourActivity.class, intent).create().visible().get();
```